# How to have only one opened accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of accordions, but I only want to allow a single one to be expanded at a time. Currently, all can be opened.

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uaytq**

```
$('.collapse-toggle').click(function (e) {
    var that = $(this).parent();
    var accordion = that.find('.collapse-content');

    if (accordion.hasClass('open')) {
        accordion.removeClass('open');
        accordion.animate({ height: 0 }, 300);
    } else {
        var currentHeight = accordion.height(); //save current height
        accordion.css('height', 'auto');        //temporary switch height to auto
        var autoHeight = accordion.height();    //get auto height
        accordion.css('height', currentHeight); //switch back to current height
        accordion.animate({ height: autoHeight }, 300); //animate that beautiful thing
        accordion.addClass('open');             //let the people know!
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm missing your HTML Markup... Please make a JSFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to close the current opened one before opening a new one.

`$('.collapse-content.open')` will target the currently opened accordion. If you have more than 1 accordion on the page, then you need to traverse further up the dom tree to get the parent container (`.wrap` in this case) of the current accordion

```
if (accordion.hasClass('open')) {
    accordion.removeClass('open');
    accordion.animate({ height: 0 }, 300);
} else {
    $('.collapse-content.open').animate({ height: 0 }, 300).removeClass('open');
    var currentHeight = accordion.height(); //save current height
    accordion.css('height', 'auto');        //temporary switch height to auto
    var autoHeight = accordion.height();    //get auto height
    accordion.css('height', currentHeight); //switch back to current height
    accordion.animate({ height: autoHeight }, 300); //animate that beautiful thing
    accordion.addClass('open');             //let the people know!
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ufskl

I am not sure what your open class does but if it has some css implications later and you need to remove it at the end of the closing of the accordion item then do this

```
$('.collapse-content.open').animate({ height: 0 }, 300, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew is was something simple!